# Can I Grow A Linux Partition After Making It & Not Lose Data?

Tags: partition, gparted

I finished the Arch Linux install successfully and installed GNOME. But I think I made my partitions too small:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd96cc977

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 125831167 125829120  60G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       125831168 134219775   8388608   4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       134219776 201328639  67108864  32G 83 Linux
```

My HDD is 250Gb, but that's just advertised, so I'm going to dumb it down to 230Gb. That being said I can add a lot more data to my SDA's. I installed GParted on a DVD so I can do so.

I never used this program before, so I want to know is, is it possible to grow the partitions, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Which ones do you want to enlarge? `sda3` is probably easy since it has the free space just behind it, `sda1` by 4G and giving up the swap (usually not needed on today's desktop machines with 4G RAM or more) is probably easy, the rest is "really really make a backup beforehand" territory.

Comment: So I can add data to sda3 but not 1? Seems good. How can I do this? Just add data in a section in GParted?

Comment: If you edit the question and include the full output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`  (you don't need "sudo" if you are running as root) then people will be able to give you more explicit answers, rather than generic responses around filesystem resizing.

Comment: I added the output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing partitions into the free space after them works pretty well with gparted. Of course you should have a backup for safety, especially when you're not experienced with the procedure. As far as I remember, gparted offers to resize the filesystem after you've resized the partition, that would be the easiest way. If it doesn't, "resize2fs" is the command that you'd use.

Comment: Thank You @Hans-Martin Mosner! I will be sure to do this!

Answer (score 0):

The savest way is to make a new partion and add it to the / or /home mountpoint.

Comment: But where would my data go?

Comment: they would be stored one the first partion and then on the second partion as far as know, answer this the question? If not feel free to ask more.

Comment: This is very vague. I need more of an idea on how to do this. I've already made a partition and installed Arch Linux. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do the above statement. If I made a new partition it won't have the data of the previous one.

Comment: let me check the man page of mount, I usual, don't extent space this way. I use a new path and a empty mount point, but that is not always wished.

Comment: appeandly, I can't find the notaion to bind multible partion to one mountpoint at a glance, but If you do a search with multiple partion on one mount point with your favorite search engine you should find multible discoussions, about that problem. Until I or somebody else added the informations to the anwser we need for that special case.